# Array file isset Incorrectly Returning False

Tags: php, arrays, isset

I have the following PHP code:

```
$haystack  = file("dictionary.txt");
$needle = 'john';
$flipped_haystack = array_flip($haystack);
if (isset($flipped_haystack[$needle])) {
    echo "Yes it's there!";
}
else {
    echo "No, it's not there!";
}
```

The contents of `dictionary.txt` are as follows (UTF-8 encoded):

```
john
```

For some reason I keep getting false despite the fact that `$haystack` prints out without any problem. It's just the false that I keep getting which keeps giving me issues. Alternately, I tried changing `$haystack` to the following code which in turn correctly returned as true:

```
$haystack = array("john");
```

Why is my code wrongly returning false?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably because of the line breaks at the end of each element. Try this:

```
$haystack  = file("dictionary.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

Here is a note from the [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php):

```
Each line in the resulting array will include the line ending, unless FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES is used, so you still need to use rtrim() if you do not want the line ending present.
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still incorrectly getting false even after trying this.

Comment: What result do you get for `var_dump($flipped_haystack);` after flipping it?

Comment: My original code worked out. It turns out the problem was the way it was saved. I originally saved it in Notepad as UTF-8, but just now tried saving it in Notepad++ as UTF-8 without BOM and it worked! Not sure why this was an issue.

Answer (score 2):

The problem relies on the fact that `file`:

> Returns the file in an array. Each element of the array corresponds to
>   a line in the file, with the newline still attached.

Therefore `john` is not equal to `john\n`.

Just set the following flag:

```
file("dictionary.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `file()` function is adding new line characters to the array elements.

See the manual page: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

Open the file this way:

```
$haystack = file('dictionary.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
```

Also, to aid in debugging, you can add lines like these:

```
var_dump($haystack);

var_dump($flipped_haystack);
```

Which would have shown you this:

```
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  string(5) "john\n"
}
array(1) {
  'john
' =>
  int(0)
}
No, it's not there!
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but am still getting false. When I added the debugging lines you suggested, I get: array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "john" } array(1) { ["john"]=> int(0) }

Comment: Hmm, something must be wrong with your file, should not be string(7) "john", should be string(4) "john".  On my system: array(1) {
  [0] =>
  string(4) "john"
}
array(1) {
  'john' =>
  int(0)
}
Yes it's there!

Answer (score 1):

Use the parameter `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES`  as there may be some newlines from the file getting read in the array

$haystack  = file("dictionary.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php